# Help with Continuity of Lebesgue measure m using intersection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $...B_2\subset B_1$ be a countable collection of measurable sets and m($B_1) < \infty$.

Show that m($\cap_{k=1}^n B_k$) = lim$_{n-> \infty} m(B_k)$

I have already shown that m($\cup_{k=1}^n A_k$) = lim$_{n-> \infty} m(A_k)$ so I think that I should use this, but I can't quite figure out how since m($\cap_{k=1}^n B_k$) = m(($\cup_{k=1}^n B_k^c)^c)$ and I have no idea what happens to Lebesgue measure under complementation

Comment: "I have no idea what happens to Lebesgue measure under complementation" That's not true. You know that if $E\subset [0,1]$ is measurable, then $m([0,1]\setminus E= 1-m(E).$

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable sets, then $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)$.

Let $A_k:=B_1\setminus B_k$. $\ $ Then $\ m(A_k)+m(B_k)=m(B_1)$.